# curl got error "transfer closed with outstanding read data remaining"

Tags: curl

I use Laravel HTTP Client to request third party API, sometimes it will throw an exception:

```
Message：cURL error 18: transfer closed with outstanding read data remaining (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)
File：/data/htdocs/cms-server/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Handler/CurlFactory.php（187）
```

Then, I try to request that url by using curl command in terminal:

```sh
curl -v http://example...
```

I notice that there is an error message in the response body, and the content is incomplete.

[image]

It is strange that sometimes it's normal，sometimes not.

By the way, the response header is:

[image]

What is the cause of the problem? How can I solve the problem? Any help will be appreciate~

Comment: It might suggest that the stream of chunks from the server is either sent incorrectly by the server or the connection is prematurely disconnected.

Comment: @DanielStenberg Thanks for your answer. It was solved by the provider. It's caused by the server reasons. Probably the Nginx proxy_temp permission problem.